# Updating a property from an overridden SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I need to override SaveChanges() so that I can update a column (NewClub.LastActivityDate) when certain entities get modified. The problem is that many times the table (NewClub) that has LastActivityDate is not in the entity set being presented to SaveChanges() so I need a way to update NewClub.LastActivityDate if it's in the entity set or not.

Here is what I have so far.

Thanks for looking

```
public override int SaveChanges()
        {

            var saveSuccess = false;
            var newClubPrimaryKeyId = 0;

            ObjectContext ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

            List<ObjectStateEntry> objectStateEntryList =
           ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added
                                                      | EntityState.Unchanged // need this to get to NewClub when it's not the table being updated
                                                      | EntityState.Modified
                                                      | EntityState.Deleted).ToList();

            foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in objectStateEntryList)
            {
                //Skip over relationships
                if (entry.IsRelationship) continue;

                //Make sure the entity is a member of the NCO schema: NewClub[...]
                if (SecurityHelper.IsValidNewClubTableName(entry.EntitySet.Name))

                {
                    entityInfoStr += "Entity Name: " + entry.EntitySet.Name + " Entity State: " + entry.State;
                    var nc = entry.Entity as NewClub;
                    var ncp = entry.Entity as NewClubProspect;

                    if (nc != null) { newClubPrimaryKeyId = nc.Id; }

                    else if (ncp != null){newClubPrimaryKeyId = ncp.NewClubId;}

                    //... More comparisons here....


                   //---------------------------------------------------------------
                   //Update NewClub.LastActivityDate where Id == newClubPrimaryKeyId
                   //----------------------------------------------------------------

                    //This does not work
                     string q = @"UPDATE NewClub SET LastActivityDate=" + DateTime.Now + " WHERE Id=" +
                           newClubPrimaryKeyId;
                      var t = ctx.CreateQuery<NewClub>(q);
                }
            }

            try
            {

                 saveSuccess = base.SaveChanges() > 0;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string ex = e.ToString();


            }

            return saveSuccess ? 1 : 0; 
        }
```

Comment: have you try to use reflection ((GetProperties)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx])an search in the current object a property of type NewClub ?

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it comes back null:  var test = ctx.GetType().GetProperty("NewClub").GetValue(ctx, null);

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually write a SQL query for this, the entry object gives you access to the current and last state of your object.

Try something like this

```
foreach( var entry in objectStateEntryList)
{
    var lastTime = entry.Property("LastActivityDate");
    if(lastTime != null)
    {
        lastTime.CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
        lastTime.IsModified = true; // be careful with this, throws exception if object is added not modified
    }
}
```

You may also want to check out EFHooks https://github.com/visoft/EFHooks